# Label value is outside the valid range

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

```
X = tf.placeholder(shape=(1, 5, 7), name='inputs', dtype=tf.float32)
X_flat = tf.layers.flatten(X)
y = tf.placeholder(shape=(1), name='outputs', dtype=tf.int32)
hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(X_flat, 150, kernel_initializer=he_init)
hidden2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden1, 50, kernel_initializer=he_init)
logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden2, 1, kernel_initializer=he_init)
with tf.name_scope("loss"):
    xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=y)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy, name="loss")
```

So I get the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Received a label value of 1 which is outside the valid range of [0, 1).  Label values: 1
```

My labels have integers that range from 0 to 4. I'm curious as to why this is not working. When I worked with MNIST in a sample code, I don't think the y training set was in the range of 0 to 1, but apparently that is what is going on here.

How do I make the cross entropy function work? Is there any sort of normalization which will make the code work?

Also how come MNIST can use integers but this one cannot for the labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

Just to be sure, this is what I changed into.

```py
X = tf.placeholder(shape=(1, 5, 7), name='inputs', dtype=tf.float32)
X_flat = tf.layers.flatten(X)
y = tf.placeholder(shape=(1), name='outputs', dtype=tf.int32)
hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(X_flat, 150, kernel_initializer=he_init)
hidden2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden1, 50, kernel_initializer=he_init)
logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden2, 5, kernel_initializer=he_init)
with tf.name_scope("loss"):
    xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=y)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy, name="loss")
```

This runs without problem on my end.

### Original

Okay. So if your `y` variable has range `(0,4)`, then your logit needs to have the shape `(batch_size, 5)` (in your case, `(1,5)`), since each value is your model's confidence on a particular label.

This:

```py
logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden2, 1, kernel_initializer=he_init)
```

Needs to be this:

```py
logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden2, 5, kernel_initializer=he_init)
```

To do even better, you should probably define these variables.

```py
num_classes = 5
# ...
logits = tf.layers.dense(hidden2, num_classes, kernel_initializer=he_init)
# ...
```

Comment: I added the suggested changes, but I now get this: ValueError: Rank mismatch: Rank of labels (received 2) should equal rank of logits minus 1 (received 2). I think it has something to do with the batch size

Comment: Edited. Please check.

Comment: This works, thanks. If I were to output multiple values per instance (an output tensor), would the y placeholder shape? (I'm also assuming I would change it from sparse softmax).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? Do you mean having a `batch_size` bigger than 1? (Like your `X` having shape `(n, 5, 7)` where `n>1`?) Btw, if this has worked as an answer, please do tick the little check to accept the answer.

Comment: Not the batch size but to choose multiple possible outputs. So for example classes 1 and 2 can be the output, as opposed to just 1 of those.